# Open a secured URL containing a pdf file using javascript in safari by passing username and password

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage where i show a list of links pointing to pdf files. These links are https links, which require username.password to access the link. My requirement is that when i click on the link.. it should open the pdf file referred by link in an iframe, without asking for username.password? 
right now when i click on the URL it first shows me a prompt to enter username/password and then opens the pdf file in the same page itself.

please help me with this?

Comment: You're going to have to show us some code and tell us how it's authenticating the username and password

Comment: right now i am not doing any authentication in my code... I am referring the doc as below  <a href="{Uri}"  target="_blank">Download Document</a> ... when i click on this the browser asks for user name and password... once i enter them i am taken to that document

Comment: Give us the URL then. We've got to know how the authentication is done to be able to tell you how to automate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That authentication mechanism sounds like plain HTTP authentication. `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` are considered different domains. If you've authenticated before on `http://example.com`, you need to re-authenticate for `https://example.com`. If this is the case, the solution is simple: either use `https://example.com` for everything or stick to `http://example.com`.

If the username/ password combination is not really sensitive, you could pass it to the URL as well:

```
https://user:pass@example.com/your-document.ext
```

Note that modern browsers will probably ask you whether you want to login with the given credentials before opening the link.

The above behavior is not dependent on Javascript. If you want to force `https` on your page with Javascript, use:

```
<script>
if (location.protocol == "http:") {
    location.href = location.href.replace(/^http/, "https");
}
</script>
```